# Testing a C++ library with Python

Tags: c++, python, shared-libraries

I have a libfoo.so library built from C++ code (compiled with gcc), and I would like to quickly test some of its exported classes (basically, instantiating a class then calling its methods to check the output).

While I could do that in C/C++ with a main file that links to the library in question and build my tests, but I think it would be much easier if it was possible to simply call Python from the command line and call the methods from there.

I know I can use CDLL from ctypes to load C-style libraries, but is there a similar functionality for C++ libraries and objects?

EDIT : Ideally, I do not want to modify the C++ code, I would need to use it as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Chris answer. However, I want to point out that [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) supports C++ (with some limitations).

Answer (score 10):

Honestly C++ is a bit messy. You could do something like create a pure C function which wraps the C++ functionality (which you then call from python) but at that point you might as well write your tests in C++. Unfortunately the only tool out there for this (that I know of) is SWIG.

It's sad that it's called the "simplified" wrapper and interface generator, because there's nothing simple about it. If you have VERY primitive data types in your signatures (like, JUST ints or maybe char*) it'll be a pretty quick job. Otherwise you have to tell swig how to marshal your data types between languages, and that gets REALLY ugly very quickly. Furthermore, after short time you realize you have to learn the CPython API in order to write your marshalling code.

And by that point you may as well write your own CPython wrapper without involving SWIG. You suddenly realize you've spent a good month learning a new API and feel horribly frustrated. If you're going to be doing this a lot, it's definitely worth your time. However if this is a one-time thing, just write your tests in C / C++.

(I'm speaking from experience here)

Comment: +1 IMO this is absolutely correct. SWIG is most useful as a data interop specification if you want to use your library in _multiple_ other languages. Writing a Python wrapper is about the same, or a little more, work than just using e.g. cppunit in a separate executeable

Comment: +1 because I have been using SWIG for some simple cases and was recommending it. Good to no that it is not as practical as it looks.

Comment: If you're going to consider wrapping C++ functions with pure C code, it might be better to use CFFI (which didn't exist when this was asked/answered): https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ It will get you very pythonic code, with only one additional module to ingest header files (and optionally compile), it's relatively easy to pick up and learn, but also very limited to C.